# Targeting an element in an unordered list to give it a different a:hover property than the others

Tags: css

```
#nav {
    font-family: "futura-pt",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
}

#nav ul {
    display: table;
    width: 67%;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    padding-left: 30%;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #252525;
    display: block;
}

#nav ul li a:hover:nth-of-type(3) {
    color: white;
}
```

I am trying to target the third of my list items in my nav bar to have a different hover property than the others. I've tried using an id and nth-child() but I can't seem to target it. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the html as well.

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">On Stage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `nth-child()`. Try this:

```
#nav ul li:nth-child(3):hover a {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Actually it works even with `nth-of-type()`... your error was that you were applying the selector to the `a` tag, not to the list item :)